# Rebuilding Indexes for Embedded Derby

Tags: derby

I'm using an embedded java database to hold bus schedules. When a new schedule is made available I automatically load the new schedule into database tables and then delete old schedules from the database. This happens automatically without user intervention.

I have noticed that the database slows over time. I have a script which drops and rebuilds indexes (there are 10 of them) and after running this performance improves significantly. Currently I manually stop the system, run the script and then restart the system.

Question is is the a way of rebuilding all 10 indexes from within the java code ? If there was, I would do this immediately after deleting old schedules

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_COMPRESS_TABLE` will rebuild indexes. You can call this function on important tables during off-hours. It should not need to be done frequently. [Docs are here](http://db.apache.org/derby/docs/10.4/ref/rrefaltertablecompress.html).

However, before doing this I would make sure that the slow queries aren't resulting in full-table scans. i.e. check to make sure you're not missing an index.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow @paulh. If it worked, you're supposed to accept the answer, that's what people look for in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the above suggestion and documentation the following method works. *db* is the database connection (type java.sql.Connection). Note that the table names needed to be made uppercase to be found.

```
public void rebuildIndexes(String[] feedTables) throws SQLException {
  String feedTable;
  CallableStatement cs;

  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reclaiming unused database table space and rebuilding indexes");
  for (int i=(feedTables.length-1); i>=0; i--) {
    feedTable = feedTables[i].toUpperCase();
    logger.log(Level.INFO, String.format("  Rebuilding table %s", feedTable));
    cs = db.prepareCall("CALL SYSCS_UTIL.SYSCS_COMPRESS_TABLE(?, ?, ?)");
    cs.setString(1, "APP");
    cs.setString(2, feedTable);
    cs.setShort(3, (short) 1);
    cs.execute();
    cs.close();
  }
  logger.log(Level.INFO, "Reclaim and rebuild finished");
}
```